# Manually flush ImageCache cache?

Tags: media

Im using ImageCache but I've since modified some of the original image files in my Drupal site. The reason being I needed to modify images uploaded to nodes but don't want to manually add them all again. Can I now manually flush ImageCache's cache?

Thanks

Comment: For Drupal 7, this question has been answered [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12864/rebuild-images-from-image-style)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just display list of all presets, there are links for flushing presets.
Presets list is available at `/admin/build/imagecache/list`

Flushing urls of respective presets would be `/admin/build/imagecache/[preset_id]/flush`

Comment: So i did these flushes, and now all my images are missing. how do i fix this?

Comment: @deweydb presets should recreate automatically. I haven't used D6 for years.